# Shedlock: use lockAtMostForString from property file

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, properties, shedlock

I have code like this:

```
private static final String FOURTEEN_MIN = "PT14M";
...

@Scheduled(cron = "0 */15 * * * *")
@SchedulerLock(name = "scheduledTaskName", lockAtMostForString = FOURTEEN_MIN, lockAtLeastForString = FOURTEEN_MIN)
public void scheduledTask() {
   // do something
}
```

Now I use constant for `lockAtMostForString` but I want to take this value from property for this.
   Is there way to do it?

### P.S.

I know that I can not use annotations and rewrite it like this:

```
LockingTaskExecutor executor = new DefaultLockingTaskExecutor(lockProvider);

...

Instant lockAtMostUntil = Instant.now().plusSeconds(600);
executor.executeWithLock(runnable, new LockConfiguration("lockName", lockAtMostUntil));
```

But I prefer to use annotations.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can directly inject your property into the annotation by using the injection syntax from spring `${propertyName:defaultValue}`.

Note 1: When not declaring a `defaultValue` then spring will throw an error if the property is missing.

Note 2: This syntax can be used with almost every spring-annotation.